# How to correct tempo of MP3s converted from WMA?

Tags: audio, mp3, wma

I recently converted a load of WMAs to MP3 320bps. However, some of these files player alot slower now. The tempo needs speeding up. I imagine this went wrong during the conversion process.

Can any recommend a way to fix this in bulk? I have a linux server available to use as well as windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise trying Audacity (Free) or Adobe Soundbooth (Paid but has 30 day trial option).

Otherwise have a look at Super Utils Audio Speed Changer Pro.

http://www.superutils.com/products/audio-speed-changer-pro/